# How to put text onto multiple pen tool subpaths in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, path, pen-tool

I just spent quite a while making all sorts of paths with the pen tool, and splitting each one up into a subpath by holding control and clicking after each one was drawn. It all looks good, but when I write text on one of the paths, the rest disappear. I have each path stroked with the pencil tool but I need the actual paths to remain so I can type onto them.

Is there any way for me to do this? Am I just an idiot and missing something completely obvious? I don't normally work with the text tool so I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Paths tab located in your Layers Palette and then click on your layer with all of the sub-paths on it, probably called "Work Path"

[image]

When you apply the type to a path, it will isolate the one path—on which you've applied the type—from the others and create a new Type Path.  In the case above, I typed a bunch of gibberish on one path, hence the name.

This is why you need to click on the Work Path layer to activate those sub-paths again, so you can create another Type Path.

Comment: Ah thank you, I figured it out! I did not even know the paths tab existed to be honest, but after trying again with it open, it it turns out the first line of text I wrote automatically created a new path layer, and I just have to re-select the original path layer to continue.